# Arbitrary length bytes to int builtin in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, int, endianness

I'm looking for a function that takes an **arbitrary length** `bytes` object, and converts it to an `int`. Obviously endianness is a required parameter to this function.

I'm certain I encountered a builtin on either `bytes` or `int`, but can't find it anymore. There are plenty of answers on similar questions involving use of `struct`, and manually enumerating the individual byte values. Is there a builtin that does this conversion without using C-like assumptions/modules?

```
def int(bytes, 'little') -> int
```

Comment: This isn't a duplicate because the other question is for 16-bit integers, and this is for arbitrary length integers.

Comment: I agree this is not a duplicate, the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402743/python-2-7-equivalent-of-built-in-method-int-from-bytes appears to be relevant however

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since 3.2:

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xFF\x00','little')
255
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xFF\x00','big')
65280
```

Comment: It would be nice to have a python2 version, too.