# python 2.7 equivalent of built-in method int.from_bytes

Tags: python, python-2.7, compatibility

I'm trying to make my project python2.7 and 3 compatible and python 3 has the built in method int.from_bytes. Does the equivalent exist in python 2.7 or rather what would be the best way to make this code 2.7 and 3 compatible?

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b"f483", byteorder="big")
1714698291
```

Comment: If you're specifically looking for a cross-version solution then you should make this clear in the title.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can treat it as an encoding (Python 2 specific):

```
>>> int('f483'.encode('hex'), 16)
1714698291
```

Or in Python 2 and Python 3:

```
>>> int(codecs.encode(b'f483', 'hex'), 16)
1714698291
```

The advantage is the string is not limited to a specific size assumption. The disadvantage is it is unsigned.

Comment: hah I like this solution ... alot ... its one I would not have thought of :) it has the added advantage of not having to know anything about the input

Comment: Yours is better really cause it should work in Python 2 and 3. Thanks tho

Comment: What would be the reverse of this? I'd like to retrieve the original byte string from the integer

Comment: What about `ord(b'\x11')`?

Answer (score 12):

```
struct.unpack(">i","f483")[0]
```

maybe?

`>` means big-endian and `i` means signed 32 bit int

see also: https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Comment: it won't work for anything bigger than int32 of course. any hints?

Comment: When the bytes is less than 4 this won't work, when it would have worked for int.from_bytes()

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module to unpack your bytes into integers.

```
import struct
>>> struct.unpack("<L", "y\xcc\xa6\xbb")[0]
3148270713L
```

Comment: that just unpacks them into bytes ... he wants them all as 1 32 bit integer ... maybe bigger ... but you are right that stuct is the module to use :)

Comment: I didn't realize he needed the actual integer values, but yeah, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
> import binascii

> barray = bytearray([0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF])
> n = int(binascii.hexlify(barray), 16)
> print("0x%02X" % n)

0xABCDEF
```