# Error unpack requires a string argument of length 16

Tags: python

Using Python 2.7 I had this code:

```
#Create a random 56 bit (7 byte) string
random_bytes = os.urandom(7)
random_bytes = int.from_bytes(random_bytes, byteorder="big")
```

Which gives the error:

> AttributeError: type object 'int' has no attribute 'from_bytes'

After reading online it looks like `from_bytes` is Python 3. So I tried the following:

```
  random_bytes = os.urandom(7)
  #random_bytes = int.from_bytes(random_bytes, byteorder="big")
  random_bytes = struct.unpack('>16B', random_bytes)
```

But this gives the following error:

> struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 16

Should the `>16B` be `>7B`? Even with that it seems to return a tuple.

**The goal is to use `random_bytes` like this:**

```
int(str(((time_bytes << 56) | random_bytes)) + code)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402743/python-2-7-equivalent-of-built-in-method-int-from-bytes does this help?

Comment: @timgeb No I'm sure ``struct.unpack`` is the way to go here

Comment: You're asking struct to unpack a 7 byte sequence into a tuple of 16, 8 bit integers...

Comment: Your goal statement doesn't need all those parenthesis or type conversions, it can be written simply as: `time_bytes << 56 | random_bytes + code` (it will be an int, and operator precedence is the same as your parens..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
r = chr(0) + os.urandom(7)  # pad with zeroes
struct.unpack('>q', r)
```

`q` being the code for signed 8-byte integer (`Q` is unsigned).

The result is a tuple with one element.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help:

```
import os

binary = os.urandom(7)
result = int(binary.encode('hex'), 16)
```